# Vaadin 14 - Cannot get a Details/AccordionPanel to use window width

Tags: java, vaadin14

Unlike many other Vaadin "container" components, the `com.vaadin.flow.component.details.Details` and `com.vaadin.flow.component.accordion.AccordionPanel` classes do not allow for `setSizeFull()` (I have tried both). I'm trying to figure out how to have one of these on a form and have it expand horizontally across the parent view. Instead, it's showing a narrow view that is not very useful. It has some reasonable vertical size. I need to know how to control the size of this component.

Here is the form class:

```
@CssImport("./styles/shared-styles.css")
public class EditTaskForm extends VerticalLayout {

  ...
  private Grid<TaskNote>          grid;

  public EditTaskForm() {
    this.addClassName("edit-task-form");
    this.setSizeFull();
    configureView();
    ...
  }
    
  private void configureView() {
    Div title = new Div();
    title.setText("Edit Task");
    title.addClassName("page-title");

    add(title, configDetails(), configNotes(), configDates(), configButtons());
    setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.START);
  }

  ...

  private Component configNotes() {
    grid = new Grid<>();

    grid.addColumn(TaskNote::getNote).setHeader("Note");

    grid.addColumn(new LocalDateTimeRenderer<>(TaskNote::getDateCreated, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
        .setHeader("Created");
    grid.addColumn(new LocalDateTimeRenderer<>(TaskNote::getDateModified, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
        .setHeader("Last Modified");

    grid.getColumns().forEach(col -> {
      col.setAutoWidth(true);
      col.setResizable(true);
    });

    grid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener(event -> {
      editNote(event.getValue());
    });

    Details details = new Details("Notes", grid);
    details.setOpened(false);
    return details;
  }
    
  ...
}
```

I tried different variations, where I inserted a `VerticalLayout` (that has `setSizeFull()`) into the mix, such that I returned a `Details` -> `VerticalLayout` -> `Grid`, but that changed nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently Details and Accordion don’t implement HasSize, so they don’t have the required methods.

You can use the lower level element API to set the width and height as a workaround:

```
details.getElement().getStyle().set("width", "100%");
```

Another option is to use `Alignment.STRETCH`.